# Dplyr Filtering Dates Only by Difference in Month & Day & Year, Not by Date Itself

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I am currently trying to utilize shiny to create a reactive data frame using the method shown below. I have been trying to pass user input from shiny into my reactively filtered data frame. However, I ran into issues and decided to hard code dates to identify what was wrong. Unfortunately, when I returned my data frame it only contained rows with dates between the individual month, day, and year values. Thus, if my minimum date is Feb 3rd, 1981 and my maximum date is April 4th, 1982, only dates with months: Feb - April, days: 3rd - 4th, & years: 1981-82 are returned. I should be getting back all dates between the two specified, but instead get all dates in the range of each "month-month/day-day/year-year". Does anyone know how to resolve this using the same filtering method?

```
crimeDataFull <- read.csv("Crime_Data.csv",  stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
crimeDataCut <- select(crimeDataFull, Occurred.Date, Crime.Subcategory, 
Precinct, Neighborhood)
     crimeDataCut$Occurred.Date <-as.Date(crimeDataCut$Occurred.Date)
     crimeDataReact <- reactive({filter(crimeDataCut, 
                                Occurred.Date >= as.Date("12/03/1900") &
                                Occurred.Date <= as.Date("12/03/2017"),
                                Precinct == input$selectPrecinct)
                               })
```

`

Comment: Please include a sample of your data by typing `dput(crimeDataFull)` and pasting the output. We cannot help if we can;t reporoduce the issue

Comment: Also, does your code correctly filter outside the shiny? Or do you have the same issues running directly in R?